# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin 3.0.0 to 3.0.1

Tags: c#, .net, azure

Interesting dependency issue...

VS2015.3, .NET45 updating Microsoft.Owin from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1 (traced this update to be the problem - wanting to install https://www.nuget.org/packages/IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation/)

[image]
it works locally on IIS Express

but publish to Azure website: (am removing additional files at destination on azure publish straight from VS).  restarted and deleted all files from azure webserver too.

[image]

web.config translation looks okay

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />   
</dependentAssembly>
```

**Edit**
Bruce Chen's answer pointed me in the direction of Kudu (Azure - Development Tools, Advanced Tools)

[image]

I downloaded the Owin dll, and it was the wrong version ie 3.0.0

To fix I cleared out all package artifacts from my solution

git clean -xfd   (be careful)

Then rebuilt

Comment: check your package the version didn't match with the web config

Comment: Try to delete packages folder and restore all nuget packages.  Double check that Microsoft.Owin is referenced under "references" and check the properties to view which version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

In general, this means that the .NET Assembly loader could not find the assembly with specific version that was referenced. Please make sure this assembly with version 3.0.1.0 could be found in your Azure website and the version matches the definition in your web.config via KUDU or FTP client.

As you said, it works locally on IIS Express, please try to deploy your website content manually to Azure via KUDU or FTP client and find out whether it works or not.

Answer (score 11):

I wasted a couple of hours on this too because the reference installed by nuget had version 3.0.0 despite the nuget package being labelled 3.0.1

Making the old version newer than the new version fixed my problem:

```html
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
```

*Edit: I think(but not certain) that the reason my version was still 3.0.0.0 was because the bin folder got caught in my repo and nuget didn't want to write over the dll

Comment: This is just wrong :)

   <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.0.0" newVersion="3.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>

Let all references to a dll reference the latest version of Owin

Comment: @NicoJuicy not all projects can rely on latest version. sometimes in your project you are FORCED to use a specific DLL version.

Comment: Thank you so much. This comment helped me while I had a issue with version 4.0.0.0 to 4.1.1.0
Same solution worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

It requires a new version instead of the one that you currently have.
If you are using Visual Studio right click the project --> Manage NuGet Packages --> Updates --> select the Owin nuget --> Click "Update".
As of today, the latest version is 4.0.0.
Hope it works out fine!

Answer (score 2):

Just to comment here that I saw this type of error when I upgraded to 4.1.0.0 and my issue was on Web.config where I still had 4.0.1.0. So, what you have in .csproj should match what is in Web.config. Updating or reinstalling did nothing in my case until I synced up the version numbers.

Answer (score 2):

In the NuGet Package Manager, check the version of Microsoft.Owin installed. Then update you project folder's web.config file, search for Microsoft.Owin in web.config and change "newVersion" to your NuGet Package Manager Version. This worked for me.