# Multiple Microsoft.Owin Versions with Nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, owin, openid-connect

I am in front of a feature freeze in less than a week and I am looking for a way to upgrade `Microsoft.Owin` in one project only and keep referencing the old versions in other projects.

The goal under the hood is to use `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect` with the version 4.1.0 providing me the support of `AuthorizationCode` flow.

My project is a C#, .NET web server using Owin.

PS : I am asking for a solution that doesn't modify the other project's `*.csproj` or `*.config`

And when I build and launch it, I got this error in the event viewer because there is a binding redirect on other projects that reference the version 3.1.0

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
>
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> File name: 'Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: Can't you update the nuget package only on the desired project?

Comment: Yes I did it but when I build and launch the app, I have this message in the Event Viewer : 
`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`

Comment: Hmm, check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276347/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-owin-3-0-0-to-3-0-1)